# how can i zoom a portion of my view based iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2

I am using iPhone SDK 3.2. I have drawn some lines on an UIView like road on a small city and added that as subview to the main view window(controller view). Now I need to zoom it from different point of view like a more specific aria of that city.

FYI: I am a new programmer in Obj-C as well iPhone app development.

Comment: please let me know for additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the info. I guess the question that I need to ask is this: will the lines and background color be in an image or will they be drawn as lines and color. An images of lines and color would be one process and lines and color would be another process.

If you are going for the lines and color route then have a look into Core Graphics (CG). It will give you the tools to put lines on the screen and fill them with color. From there you will need to calculate the math to make them appear to zoom.

Alternatively look into OpenGL. It will provide you with the tools to create a 3D environment that will allow  you to zoom. 
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html

Good luck

Comment: thanks @DecodingSand, i will try either way and inform u soon.

Comment: I have found the framework cocos2d-http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/, which is very helpful for 2d programming. As far i can understand, this will resolve my current problem. Thanks @DecodingSand for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer this one unfortunately but you will need a little more information to get an answer this one

1) do you need the image to stay sharp?

2) is the original image that you are zooming a photograph or shapes like circles, squares and type?

3) if it is a photograph then is the resolution higher then the resolution of the screen (hi res photo)

Comment: no images are used now. only background color and lines are used here. later i will add some images, but not now. thanks for your response

Comment: I have added some additional info. If you need any more , please let me know.